# OAuth Twitter Authentication

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I'm having authentication issues with the Twitter API, the question is regarding tokens. Our client has provided us with their updated Access Token and Access Token Secret, however I'm still getting failed "Could not authenticate you" Code 32 error. Do the Access Token/Secret depend on Consumer Key & Secret? Meaning the authentication will fail unless all four of the OAuth tokens are correct?

I created a test Twitter dev account and tested out new Access Token & Secret and Consumer Key & Secret so I know our service is working properly.